# Searching for label:foo and -label:bar in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I am trying to delete a few thousand threads, more than I could do manually.

When I search for

> label:github -label:dont_delete -to:me@example.com

I see threads with the dont_delete label.  Why?  How can I get only threads that are labeled github, but not labeled dont_delete and not to me directly?

Comment: I expect that part of the issue is that Gmail assigns labels to individual messages, not whole conversations, even though it looks that way. The conversations that are coming up probably don't have that label on all the messages therein. I'll bet if you re-apply that label to those conversations that they'll then disappear from your search.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54299/41003